# Tomcat Realm: Not able to set realm for my web application

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, jdbcrealm

I am trying to set Tomcat JDBC Realm for my Testing web application. I am following the standard documentation, https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JDBCRealm.

My server.xml is as following:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
</GlobalNamingResources>

<Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

        <!-- Default Realm -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
                   resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
        </Realm>

        <!-- Mine implementation -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
               driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbSecurity?user=root&amp;password=root"
               userTable="users"
               userNameCol="user_name"
               userCredCol="user_pass"
               userRoleTable="user_roles"
               roleNameCol="role_name"/>

        <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
              unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                   prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
                   pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

I didn't made any changes in my application.
What other changes I need to do to get it working?

###### EDITED

I tried context.xml in application, that didn't work either.

src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml

```
<Context>
    <Resource
            name="jdbc/dbSecurity"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            removeAbandoned="true"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="15"
            maxActive="5"
            maxIdle="5"
            maxWait="7000"
            username="root"
            password="root"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbSecurity?autoReconnectForPools=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            validationQuery="SELECT '1';"
            testOnBorrow="true"/>
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
           driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           connectionName="root"
           connectionPassword="root"
           connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbSecurity?autoReconnectForPools=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
           userTable="users"
           userNameCol="user_name"
           userCredCol="user_pass"
           userRoleTable="user_roles"
           roleNameCol="role_name"/>
</Context>
```

My webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml is as given:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.restroshop</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have a jersey RESTful resource :

```
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

And an index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Jersey RESTful Web Application!</h2>
<p><a href="webapi/myresource">Jersey resource</a>
<p>Visit <a href="http://jersey.java.net">Project Jersey website</a>
    for more information on Jersey!
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="appCtrl">{{greet}}</div>
    <div ng-controller="orderCtrl">{{greet}}</div>
</div>
<script src="app/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.controller.js"></script>
<script src="app/Orders/orders.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/Orders/orders.controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

GitHub 
[Repository](https://github.com/kuldeepiitg/Tomcat-Angular-Jersey/tree/master/test/src/main/java/com/restroshop) 
link

Comment: What errors are you getting? What Java code are you using to access the DataSource?

Comment: Do I need to write explicit implementation of Realm? I think default implementation i.e. JDBCRealm is sufficient to connect to database.

Comment: You don't need to write a new implementation, but if you want to access the DB in your code, you have to tell it to use the DataSource. We'll need to see that code, as well as any errors you are getting. Saying "It doesn't work" doesn't give SO users enough information to help you.

Comment: @Cody I am sharing more code. Wait for a while.

Comment: I want to access my website as tomcat manager-gui. Tomcat manager It appears with a popup asking for username and password. http://localhost:8080/manager/html